# how i can define customized annotation on controller based on spring boot or cloud

Tags: spring, spring-boot, controller, cloud

I defined a series of annotation which could help me do some QPS measurement. I put them on controller method in spring cloud. Unfortunately, it does not work...

It does nothing if I put

```
  @Metered(tags = {"test1", "test2"})
    @Counted(tags = {"count1"})
```

on controller method.

Do I miss anything ?

```
@RestController
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class TestController {
　　private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);
@RequestMapping("exinfo")
@Metered(tags = {"test1", "test2"})
@Counted(tags = {"count1"})
public String getInfo(){
    return "success";
}
```

Comment: hi guys, could anyone help me ? or just give me hint...

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Comment: ok, I do some modification.